# developing for samsung S3 Watch

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, wearables

I was trying to develope an app (1st time) for Samsung S3 using Wear 2.0. But while trying to install it I realize that OS of Samsung S3 is Tizen.

Does that mean I cant develop for it without using Tizen SDK?

Can we use android studio(Android SDK) to develop for Samsung S3 Watch which is having Tizen OS?

Comment: You'll have to install Tizen Studio and you can use either the Tizen web or native frameworks for developing an app for Gear s3.

Answer (score 2):

The Gear S3 runs Tizen, so you'll have to use Tizen SDK. You can use Android Studio only to build applications for devices running Android Wear.